# Second sector kernel not printing strings (16-bit ASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, osdev, 16-bit

So I'm working on a 16-bit operating system, and I have loaded the second stage that will act as my kernel. The only issue is that the kernel doesn't print any strings, just blank characters.

The kernel code should print out "███ TEST", but it doesn't just moves the cursor printing blank chars.

I have attached source code of the bootloader, the kernel and the LD script that is used.

BOOTLOADER:

```
        .code16
        .global     _entry
        .section    .text.main

        .extern     _print
        .extern     _strcmp

    #
    #   Bootld. entry point
    #   just skips over BBFS
    #   disk parameters
    #
    _entry:
        jmp     _start
        nop

    #
    #   BBFS Disk parameters
    #                           
    _bbfs_disk_label:   .ascii  "TEST-TEST "    #   10 chars. for the disk label

    _bbfs_isbootable:   .byte   1               #   Is the disk bootable?   1 - yes
                                                #                           0 - no

    _bbfs_is_sysdisk:   .byte   1               #   Is this a system disk?  1 - yes
                                                #                           0 - no

    _bbfs_file_systm:   .ascii  "BBFS V03"      #   8 chars. for the FS id

    #
    #   Main bootld. function
    #
    _start:

        #   Save the boot device
        mov     %dl,    _boot_dev

        #
        #   Clear the screen
        #
        mov     $0x03,  %ax
        int     $0x10

        #   Set pallete reg.
        mov     $0x10,  %ah     # Set pallete registers
        mov     $0x03,  %al     # toggle intensity/blinking
        mov     $0x00,  %bl     # 0 - enable intensity
                                # 1 - enable blinking
        int     $0x10

        mov     $0x11,  %ah     # Set font
        mov     $0x11,  %al     # ROM BIOS 8x14 monochrome character set
        int     $0x10

        #
        #   Stack setup
        #
        xor     %ax,    %ax
        cli
        mov     $0x9000,%ax
        mov     %ax,    %ss
        mov     $0xF800,%sp
        sti

        mov     $0x13,  %ah     #   write string
        mov     $0x01,  %al     #   write mode
        mov     $0x00,  %bh     #   video page number
        mov     $0x0f,  %bl     #   attribute mode
        mov     $0x0A,  %cx     #   lenght of str
        mov     $0x00,  %dh     #   row
        mov     $0x00,  %dl     #   column
        mov     $_boot_msg, %bp #   pointer to str
        int     $0x10

    #
    #   Load the kernel file
    #   --------------------
    #
    #   KERNEL 5.5.0.SYS must be
    #   located after the bootld if
    #   not bootloader will return
    #   an error
    #

    #
    #   Check if the file located
    #   @ the second sector is
    #   called KERNEL 5.5.0
    #
    #   if not return an error
    #
    _search:
    
        #
        #   Read the 2nd sector
        #
        xor     %ax,    %ax
        mov     %ax,    %es

        mov     $0x02,  %ah
        mov     $0x01,  %al
        mov     $0xAA00,%bx
        mov     $0x00,  %ch
        mov     $0x02,  %cl
        mov     $0x00,  %dh
        movb    (_boot_dev),%dl
        int     $0x13

        xor     %ax,    %ax
        xor     %cx,    %cx

        mov     $0xAA03,%si
        mov     $_file_name,%di
        mov     $13,    %cx

        _search_loop:
            movsb
            loop    _search_loop

        mov     $_file_name,    %si
        mov     $_kernel_file,  %di
        call    _strcmp
        jc      _kernel_found

        mov     $_no_krnl_file, %si
        call    _print 

        jmp     _end

    _kernel_found:
        mov     $_found_kernel, %si
        call    _print

    _disk_read:
        xor     %ax,    %ax
        xor     %bx,    %bx
        xor     %cx,    %cx
        xor     %dx,    %dx

        mov     $0x02,  %ah
        mov     $0x0C,  %al
        mov     $0x7e00,%bx
        mov     $0x00,  %ch
        mov     $0x02,  %cl
        mov     $0x00,  %dh
        movb    (_boot_dev),%dl
        int     $0x10

        jc      _disk_error
        
        mov     $_kernel_read,%si
        call    _print

        jmp     0x7e00


    _disk_error:
        mov     $_read_fail,%si
        call    _print

    _end:
        cli
        hlt

        .section    .rodata
    _boot_msg:      .asciz  "\xDB\xDB\xDB TEST\r\n"
    
    _found_kernel:  .asciz  "BBFS: Kernel file found\r\nBBFS: Loading the kernel\r\n"
    _no_krnl_file:  .asciz  "BBFS: Kernel file not found, booting halted\r\n"
    _kernel_read:   .asciz  "BBFS: Kernel loaded, passing control\r\n"

    _read_fail:     .asciz  "BBFS: Disk read error, booting halted\r\n"

    _kernel_file:   .asciz  "KERNEL 5.5.0"

        .section    .data16
    _num_attempts:  .byte   0
    _boot_dev:      .byte   0
    _file_name:     .fill   12,1,0
```

The kernel:

```
        .code16
        .global     _kentry
        .section    .text.kernel


    _kentry:
        jmp     _kmain
        nop
    
    #
    #   BBFS File Parameters
    #   _kentry jumps over this
    #
    #
    _bbfs_file_name:        .asciz  "KERNEL 5.5.0"
    _bbfs_file_ext:         .ascii  "SYS"
    _bbfs_is_file_exec:     .byte   0
    _bbfs_is_system_file:   .byte   1
    _bbfs_day_of_month:     .ascii  "23"
    _bbfs_month_of_year:    .ascii  "12"
    _bbfs_year_of_creat:    .ascii  "2023"

    _kmain:
        xor     %ax,    %ax
        mov     %ax,    %es
        mov     %ax,    %ds
        mov     $_kentry,%sp
        cld

        mov     $0x0e,  %ah
        mov     $'a',   %al
        int     $0x10

        mov     $_msg_0,%si
        call    _printk

        cli
        hlt

        .section    .rodata.kernel
    _msg_0: .asciz  "\xDB\xDB\xDB TEST\r\n"
```

Linker script:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary);
ENTRY(_kentry);

SECTIONS
{
    .   =   0x7e00;
    .text   :   SUBALIGN(0)
    {
        *(.text.kernel);
        *(.text.libk);
        *(.text)
    }

    .rodata :   SUBALIGN(0)
    {
        *(.rodata.kernel);
        *(.rodata)
    }

    .data   :   SUBALIGN(0)
    {
        *(.data);
    }

    /DISCARD/   :   {
        *(.comment);
        *(.note*)
    }

}
```

Print function that I'm using:

```
        .code16
        .global     _printk
        .section    .text.libk

    _printk:
        lodsb

        or      %al,    %al
        jz      .pk_done

        mov     $0x0e,  %ah
        int     $0x10

        jmp     _printk

        .pk_done:
            ret
```

I have tried everything, changing the LD, setting up the stack in the kernel file, changing how the bootloader loads the kernel, switching from FAT12 to my own file system (BBFS) thinking that it may have something to do with FAT and nothing has worked! I have searched online but I just haven't been able to find any answers.

The kernel should print out "███ TEST" just like the bootloader, but it doesn't.

[Running in QEMU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6K5c.png)

Comment: Did you try to print ASCII-only characters? Init stack before calling BIOS functions in bootloader? Is `_msg_0` present in final binary? Is proper address loaded into `si`?

Comment: @dimich yes I did print ASCII only, yes I did setup the whole stack thing, yes the message i present in the binary, and it is loaded into `si`

Comment: `_disk_read:` in bootloader file should be `int $0x13` not `int $0x10`.

Comment: @Nassau thank you!! I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thank you so much

Comment: I'm curious how `a` is printed if second stage (kernel) is not loaded?